# How do I use blade to pass a variable to an image source?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

What I am trying to do is link to an image that has the same name as the `{{ $player->id }}` value that is associated with the image and the current player profile being viewed. Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
<a href="#"><img src={{asset('player_images/{{ $player->id }}.png')}} alt="{{ $player->fn }}" height="250" width="250"></a>
```

I get this error:

```
ErrorException in 3df6d770fcb0ad814f71ee3a4e14a69779b15332.php line 5:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'
```

I have also tried this,

```
<a href="#"><img src='/public/player_images/{{ $player->id }}.png') alt="{{ $player->fn }}" height="250" width="250"></a>
```

but the image will not load. I do though get the alt as the player first name, so I know that I can pass data this way, but how do I do it for the source of an image? I realize the first set of code most likely is failing because of the {{}} embedded within the {{}}, but I don't understand why the second method doesn't work. Any help on why this isn't working or how I could accomplish another way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<a href="#"><img src={{asset("player_images/{{ $player->id }}.png")}} alt="{{ $player->fn }}" height="250" width="250"></a>`

Comment: @AlivetoDie still receiving the same error

Comment: did you tried my answer @hoolakoola

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

```
<a href="#"><img src={{asset('player_images/'.$player->id.'.png')}} alt="{{ $player->fn }}" height="250" width="250"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is proper way to use

```
<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('player_images').'/'.$player->id.'.png'}}" alt="{{ $player->fn }}" height="250" width="250"></a>
```

Note :  In Blade `{{ $player->id.'.png' }}` is equivalent to `<?php echo $player->id.'.png' ?>`